# How do I get the max from a partitioned query using Rank ()

Tags: t-sql

[image: Rank]

I want the result to return the max Rank when partitioned using the rank function.
I am using the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.pomst.co_num
    ,dbo.pomst.wh_num
    ,dbo.pomst.po_number
    ,dbo.pomst.po_suffix
    ,dbo.pomst.vendor_id
    ,dbo.item.uom
    ,dbo.item.upc_num
    ,dbo.item.item_desc
    ,RIGHT(dbo.auditlog.pallet_id, 8) AS pallet_id
    ,dbo.auditlog.abs_num
    ,dbo.auditlog.item_qty
    ,dbo.auditlog.lot
    ,dbo.auditlog.packer
    ,auditlog.comments
    ,auditlog.date_time
    ,rank() OVER (
        PARTITION BY auditlog.comments ORDER BY auditlog.date_time ASC
        ) AS CorrectTrans
FROM dbo.auditlog
INNER JOIN dbo.pomst ON dbo.auditlog.co_num = dbo.pomst.co_num
    AND dbo.auditlog.wh_num = dbo.pomst.wh_num
    AND dbo.auditlog.po_number = dbo.pomst.po_number
    AND dbo.auditlog.po_suffix = dbo.pomst.po_suffix
INNER JOIN dbo.item ON dbo.auditlog.co_num = dbo.item.co_num
    AND dbo.auditlog.wh_num = dbo.item.wh_num
    AND dbo.auditlog.abs_num = dbo.item.abs_num
WHERE (dbo.pomst.co_num = 'AC01')
    AND (dbo.pomst.wh_num = 'KU22')
    AND (dbo.pomst.row_status = 'C')
    AND (dbo.auditlog.trans_type = 're')
    AND item_qty NOT LIKE '-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I was trying to get the max result of a rank, but if I flip order of rank from asc to desc and use a CTE I can select the the results that always have 1 as the rank as opposed to trying to get the Max. I would still like to know how to get the Max rank but this solution suits my needs.

```
;with cte as
(SELECT DISTINCT dbo.pomst.co_num
    ,dbo.pomst.wh_num
    ,dbo.pomst.po_number
    ,dbo.pomst.po_suffix
    ,dbo.pomst.vendor_id
    ,dbo.item.uom
    ,dbo.item.upc_num
    ,dbo.item.item_desc
    ,RIGHT(dbo.auditlog.pallet_id, 8) AS pallet_id
    ,dbo.auditlog.abs_num
    ,dbo.auditlog.item_qty
    ,dbo.auditlog.lot
    ,dbo.auditlog.packer
    ,auditlog.comments
    ,auditlog.date_time
    ,rank() OVER (
        PARTITION BY auditlog.comments ORDER BY auditlog.date_time desc
        ) AS CorrectTrans
FROM dbo.auditlog
INNER JOIN dbo.pomst ON dbo.auditlog.co_num = dbo.pomst.co_num
    AND dbo.auditlog.wh_num = dbo.pomst.wh_num
    AND dbo.auditlog.po_number = dbo.pomst.po_number
    AND dbo.auditlog.po_suffix = dbo.pomst.po_suffix
INNER JOIN dbo.item ON dbo.auditlog.co_num = dbo.item.co_num
    AND dbo.auditlog.wh_num = dbo.item.wh_num
    AND dbo.auditlog.abs_num = dbo.item.abs_num
WHERE (dbo.pomst.co_num = 'AC01')
    AND (dbo.pomst.wh_num = 'KU22')
    AND (dbo.pomst.row_status = 'C')
    AND (dbo.auditlog.trans_type = 're')
    AND item_qty NOT LIKE '-%'
)
Select * from cte
where CorrectTrans = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add select and group by and use your existing query as a sub query.

Try ..

```
    select max([CorrectTrans]), Vendor_Id, Item_qty, Lot, Pallet_id
from (
-- Your existing query --
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.pomst.co_num
    ,dbo.pomst.wh_num
    ,dbo.pomst.po_number
    ,dbo.pomst.po_suffix
    ,dbo.pomst.vendor_id
    ,dbo.item.uom
    ,dbo.item.upc_num
    ,dbo.item.item_desc
    ,RIGHT(dbo.auditlog.pallet_id, 8) AS pallet_id
    ,dbo.auditlog.abs_num
    ,dbo.auditlog.item_qty
    ,dbo.auditlog.lot
    ,dbo.auditlog.packer
    ,auditlog.comments
    ,auditlog.date_time
    ,rank() OVER (
        PARTITION BY auditlog.comments ORDER BY auditlog.date_time ASC
        ) AS CorrectTrans
    FROM dbo.auditlog
    INNER JOIN dbo.pomst ON dbo.auditlog.co_num = dbo.pomst.co_num
    AND dbo.auditlog.wh_num = dbo.pomst.wh_num
    AND dbo.auditlog.po_number = dbo.pomst.po_number
    AND dbo.auditlog.po_suffix = dbo.pomst.po_suffix
    INNER JOIN dbo.item ON dbo.auditlog.co_num = dbo.item.co_num
    AND dbo.auditlog.wh_num = dbo.item.wh_num
    AND dbo.auditlog.abs_num = dbo.item.abs_num
    WHERE (dbo.pomst.co_num = 'AC01')
    AND (dbo.pomst.wh_num = 'KU22')
    AND (dbo.pomst.row_status = 'C')
    AND (dbo.auditlog.trans_type = 're')
    AND item_qty NOT LIKE '-%'
    -- =======================================
) x
group by Vendor_id, Item_qty, Lot, Pallet_id
```